# How to code the complete graph $K_8$ but with two edges between each vertex?

Tags: graphs

I understand it would look horribly cluttered -- but I can't figure out how to even go about starting to create this in LaTeX.

See: https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Category:Complete_graph_K8

Comment: Could you please explain what the/a $K_8$ graph is?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\tikzset{
  Bullet/.style     = {fill=blue!66,draw,color=blue!66,circle,minimum size=4.55pt,scale=0.4},
}
\newcommand{\N}{8}
\newcommand{\Rad}{3}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\foreach \X in {1,...,\N}
{
\node[Bullet] (corner\X) at ({\X*360/\N+180/\N-90}:\Rad) {};
}
\foreach \X in {1,...,\N}
{
\foreach \Y in {\X,...,\N}
{
\draw[-,double] (corner\X)--(corner\Y);
}
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: \pgfmathsetmacro\angle{(\i-1/2)*360/\N} (finished some secs after you :P)

Comment: @koleygr I had practice [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/412054/121799). And sorry, I do not understand your comment, is there something wrong with my code?

Comment: @marmot not... Just solved it the same time as you.. and commented to let you edit your angle with the easier formula before delete my comment. (The angle is 360/8 ... so 360/\N rotated left by half of this angle ... It is much easier for someone to understand something like this [also, anyone can think any other way... but I found that simpler and supposed that it will "improve your answer"])

Comment: @koleygr I see what you mean. I had a slightly different intuition behind this (rotating the thing such that the lowest two nodes are at the same height), that's why I wrote the formula that way. How about we just leave the comments here?

Comment: No problem... I just thought that it is an easier thought. (I have found myself infinitive times to think too complicated in similar thinks... Even now, every time I need a modulo you can not imagine what I am doing... )